# Visual studio 2010 setup project localization

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encoding, localization, setup-project

I would like to change localization in visual studio 2010 (setup project properties) setup project to slovak (language)[or any other language, which is not in the menu], but in menu there are only these languages:

- neutral
- chinese
- czech
- english
- french
- german
- italian
- japanese
- korean
- polish
- portuguese
- russian
- spanish
- turkish

so my two questions are:

1. Can i import/add slovak localization into visual studio?
2. Or use english localization, but use unicode character set, because when i use english localization, i can't use characters like 'č','ť','ľ' etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use an MSI editor like Orca in the Windows SDK and use it to edit all the text in the MSI file. Unicode should work fine. To re-use that translation, start the edit with the Transform->New transform on the Orca menu, then make your changes, then Transform->Generate transform to create an mst file.  If you rebuild the MSI file you can do Transform->Apply transform to get your changes back into the MSI file. So basically you create your own translation and import it into the MSI file. In Orca, View->Summary Information you'd need to add the language code.

I don't know the internals of where VS keeps the translations or how you'd make your own.

Or you could look at other tools that create MSI files. VS support for creating MSI files has gone away.